# C++ Output Error?

Tags: c++, debugging, output

I have coded this statement.

> 1. Write a program to get the unit prices and quantities of 3 items. Program should output the subtotals with the total. If the total is greater than 10,000.00, 5% of discount should be given. Use the functions with the return types as described below.
>      a.  Name: input, Return Type: void
>      Description: take the value of the unit price and the quantity of an item.
>      b.  Name: calculateSubTotal,Return Type: double
>      Description: calculate the subtotal for a particular item.
>      c.  Name: print
>      Return Type: void
>      Description: should print the last bill with the subtotal, total and discount

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void netTotal1(double &uPrice1,int &qty1)
{
    double amount1;
    cout<<"Enter Unit Price of First Item : ";
    cin>>uPrice1;
    cout<<"Enter Quantity : ";
    cin>>qty1;
    amount1=uPrice1*qty1;
}
void netTotal2(double &uPrice2,int &qty2)
{
    double amount2;
    cout<<"Enter Unit Price of Second Item : ";
    cin>>uPrice2;
    cout<<"Enter Quantity : ";
    cin>>qty2;
    amount2=uPrice2*qty2;
}
void netTotal3(double &uPrice3,int &qty3)
{
    double amount3;
    cout<<"Enter Unit Price of Third Item : ";
    cin>>uPrice3;
    cout<<"Enter Quantity : ";
    cin>>qty3;
    amount3=uPrice3*qty3;
}

double tot(double &amount1,double &amount2,double &amount3)
{
    double total;
    total=amount1+amount2+amount3;
    cout<<"\nNet Amount of First Item : "<<amount1;
    cout<<"\nNet Amount of First Item :   "<<amount1;
    cout<<"\nNet Amount of First Item : "<<amount1;
    cout<<"\nTotal of  All Items : "<<total;
}

double discount( double &total)
{
    double dsc;
    if (total>10000)
    {
        dsc=(total*0.05);
    }
    else
    {
        dsc=0;
    }
    return dsc;
}

double subTot(double &total,double &dsc)
{
    double subTotal;
    subTotal=total-dsc;

    cout<<"\nDiscount : "<<dsc;
    cout<<"\nSub Total is : " <<subTotal;
}


int main()
{
    double uPrice1,uPrice2,uPrice3,total,amount1,amount2,amount3,dsc,subTotal;
    int qty1,qty2,qty3;

    netTotal1(uPrice1,qty1);
    netTotal2(uPrice2,qty2);
    netTotal3(uPrice3,qty3);

    tot(amount1,amount2,amount3);

    discount(total);

    subTot(total,dsc);
}
```

Unfortunately there are errors in output.

```
Enter Unit Price of First Item : 10
Enter Quantity : 10
Enter Unit Price of Second Item : 10
Enter Quantity : 10
Enter Unit Price of Third Item : 10
Enter Quantity : 10

Net Amount of First Item : 5.2668e+267
Net Amount of First Item :   5.2668e+267
Net Amount of First Item : 5.2668e+267
Total of  All Items : 7.14983e+281
Discount : 1.20132e-306
Sub Total is : -1.00361e-306
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 5.957 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger? Did all variables have the expected values?

Comment: Your main problem is failing to read and follow instructions. Do what the instructions say, don't improvise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not working for you because some of your variables (like amount1, amount2 etc) are modified only locally in your functions.

Try to always initialize your variables, it will be easier to debug, now you are just printing some garbage from uninitialized variables.

If you want to modify value inside your function pass reference to it or better return some output from function and assign that output to desired variable.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void netTotal1(double &uPrice1,int &qty1, double &amount1)
{
    cout<<"Enter Unit Price of First Item : ";
    cin>>uPrice1;
    cout<<"Enter Quantity : ";
    cin>>qty1;
    amount1=uPrice1*qty1;
}
void netTotal2(double &uPrice2,int &qty2, double &amount2)
{

    cout<<"Enter Unit Price of Second Item : ";
    cin>>uPrice2;
    cout<<"Enter Quantity : ";
    cin>>qty2;
    amount2=uPrice2*qty2;
}
void netTotal3(double &uPrice3,int &qty3, double &amount3)
{
    cout<<"Enter Unit Price of Third Item : ";
    cin>>uPrice3;
    cout<<"Enter Quantity : ";
    cin>>qty3;
    amount3=uPrice3*qty3;
}

void tot(double &amount1,double &amount2,double &amount3, double &total)
{
    total=amount1+amount2+amount3;
    cout<<"\nNet Amount of First Item : "<<amount1;
    cout<<"\nNet Amount of First Item :   "<<amount1;
    cout<<"\nNet Amount of First Item : "<<amount1;
    cout<<"\nTotal of  All Items : "<<total;
}

void discount( double &total, double &dsc)
{
    if (total>10000)
    {
        dsc=(total*0.05);
    }
    else
    {
        dsc=0;
    }

}

void subTot(double &total,double &dsc)
{
    double subTotal;
    subTotal=total-dsc;

    cout<<"\nDiscount : "<<dsc;
    cout<<"\nSub Total is : " <<subTotal;
}


int main()
{
    double uPrice1,uPrice2,uPrice3,total,amount1,amount2,amount3,dsc,subTotal;
    int qty1,qty2,qty3;

    netTotal1(uPrice1,qty1, amount1);
    netTotal2(uPrice2,qty2, amount2);
    netTotal3(uPrice3,qty3, amount3);

    tot(amount1,amount2,amount3, total);

    discount(total, dsc);

    subTot(total,dsc);
}
```

Better try to return values from functions, and try not to repeat your code, slightly improved code:
    #include

```
double askForValues(double &unitPrice, int &quantity)
{
    std::cout << "Enter Unit Price of Item: ";
    std::cin >> unitPrice;
    std::cout << "Enter Quantity: ";
    std::cin >> quantity;

    return unitPrice * quantity;
}

double sumAmounts(double const amount1, double const amount2, double const amount3)
{
    double total = amount1 + amount2 + amount3;
    return total;
}

double calculateDiscount(double const totalPrice)
{
    if (totalPrice > 10000) {
         return totalPrice * 0.05;
    } else {
         return 0;
    }
}

double calculatePriceAfterDiscount(double const total, double const dsc)
{
    return total - dsc;
}

int main()
{
    double uPrice1 = 0.0, uPrice2 = 0.0, uPrice3 = 0.0;
    double amount1 = 0.0, amount2 = 0.0, amount3 = 0.0;
    double totalPrice = 0.0, discount = 0.0, priceAfterDiscount = 0.0;
    int qty1 = 0, qty2 = 0, qty3 = 0;

    amount1 = askForValues(uPrice1,qty1);
    amount2 = askForValues(uPrice2,qty2);
    amount3 = askForValues(uPrice3,qty3);

    totalPrice = sumAmounts(amount1,amount2,amount3);

    discount = calculateDiscount(totalPrice);

    priceAfterDiscount = calculatePriceAfterDiscount(totalPrice,discount);

    std::cout << "Total price after discount is: " << priceAfterDiscount << '\n';
}
```

For further improvement try to store your variables in some container, like vector. Using variables amount1, amount2 etc is really bad, what if you will have million amounts?

Comment: You Saved Me ! Thanks a Lot.Thank You Very Much brother !